# How can I query user Azure AD attributes containing hyphens?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

There are Azure AD attributes for users whose names include hyphens. For example, `msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1` or `msDS-principalName`. However, if I attempt to query those from Microsoft Graph in a `$select` or `$filter`, I get errors:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=id,msDS-principalName

{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Parsing Select and Expand failed.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "...",
            "date": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=msDS-principalName eq 'abc'

{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "...",
            "date": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find any documentation about escaping hyphens or otherwise successfully querying such attributes.

Things that don't work:

1. Escaping as `%2D`
2. Escaping with backslash
3. Omitting the hyphen

Comment: Please post your outgoing requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1` is an attribute in on-promises AD, if you want to get the user with this attribute in Azure AD, you need to use [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-version-history) to sync the 
attribute `msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1` as like `extension_3e2cd06ca3494546888b069a891b4bb6_msDS_cloudExtensionAttribute1` to Azure AD. In Azure AD, the hyphens is invalid with extension attribute name, it should match the regex `[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*`.

[image]

[image]

For more details for syncing, see this [**link**](https://ronnydejong.com/2015/09/14/use-custom-attributes-for-automatically-populate-azure-ad-dynamic-group-memberships/). After syncing, then you can use Microsoft Graph to get the user with extension attribute like below.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<object-id>?$select=extension_3e2cd06ca3494546888b069a891b4bb6_msDS_cloudExtensionAttribute1
```

[image]

Or

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=extension_3e2cd06ca3494546888b069a891b4bb6_msDS_cloudExtensionAttribute1
```